# MAUI Blazor app: combine ContentPage and NavigationPage

Tags: .net, blazor, maui

Currently I've a MAUI Blazor app with a single ContentPage with a BlazorWebView.

The user is able to search books where a list with booktitles is shown.

When the user select one of the books a booktitle detail page should open:

- If I do this with a fullscreen modal div the Back history button is
  not working.
- If I do this with navigating to a new booktitle detail page the
  searchquery and scrollbar position is gone.

Question can I solve this by using an additional MAUI NavigationPage?
If yes how to navigate from the booktitle list in the ContentPage  to the NavigationPage?

Comment: Could you provide some code related ?